# checkbox has checked values but does not show checked

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

**UPDATE**

I have been using [this file](https://github.com/santoshlinkha/prob_and_stat/blob/main/breakdown.js)
to recursively create the list of tags with the following code.

```
import React from "react";


class TagElement extends React.Component{

    updateCheck(e){
        var v = (e.target.checked)? e.target.value : false
        this.props.checkEvent(v)
    }

    render(){
        const tag_name = this.props.tagElement;
        const tag_id = Math.random();
        return(
            <div className="form-check">
                <input className    =   "form-check-input" 
                    type            =   "checkbox" 
                    defaultChecked  =   {this.props.checked}
                    name            =   {tag_name}
                    id              =   { tag_id }
                    onChange        =   {(e) => this.updateCheck(e)}
                    />
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={tag_id}>
                    { tag_name  + " " + this.props.checked }
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class TagTree extends React.Component{

    state = {
        key : "",
        val : [],
        display : "none"
    }

    onCheck(v){
        this.setState({ display : v? "block" : "none"})
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        const tagkey = Object.keys(this.props.tagTree)[0]
        const tagval = this.props.tagTree[tagkey]
        const includedActiveList = this.props.activeTags.includes(tagkey)

        this.setState(
            {
                key : tagkey,
                val : tagval,
                display : includedActiveList ? "block" : "none"
            }, () => {})
    }

    checkCheck(tag){
        return (this.props.activeTags.includes(tag))
    }

    render(){

        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <TagElement tagElement={this.state.key} 
                    checkEvent={(v) => this.onCheck(v)}
                    activeTags={this.props.activeTags}
                    checked={this.checkCheck(this.state.key)}
                    />
                <ul className="tag-check-box" style={{display: this.state.display}}>
                    <li>
                        { this.state.val.map( t => (typeof(t) === 'object') ? 
                            <TagTree tagTree={t} checkedTrue={this.state.check} 
                                key={Math.random()}
                                activeTags={this.props.activeTags}/> : 
                            <TagElement tagElement={t} key={Math.random()}
                                activeTags={this.props.activeTags}
                                checked={this.checkCheck(t)}
                                /> )}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}



class TagApp extends React.Component{
    state = {
        activeTags : ["Algebra", "Sequence and Series", "Types", "Arithmatic Progression", "Arithmatic Mean"]
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <h4>Select Tags</h4>
                <ul className="tag-check-box">
                    <li>
                        { this.props.tagList.map( t =>  
                            <TagTree tagTree={t} key={Math.random()} 
                                activeTags={this.state.activeTags} /> 
                        )}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TagApp;
```

The result is that the end node is properly displayed **checked** while the parent node is not properly **checked**.

[image]

If I inspect the HTML file then the input shows checked.

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" 
       name="Types" id="Types" value="Types" checked>
```

but it does not show the default checked.

[image]

Comment: You should update the checked prop instead of the attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you do defaultChecked or value or checked, not all of them.

```js
import React from "react";


class TagElement extends React.Component{

    updateCheck(tag_name){
        const checked = this.props.activeTags.includes(tag_name)
        this.props.checkEvent(!checked)
    }

    checkCheck(tag){
        return (this.props.activeTags.includes(tag))
    }

    render(){
        const tag_name = this.props.tagElement;

        return(
            <div className="form-check">
                <input className="form-check-input" 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    name = {tag_name}
                    id={ tag_name }
                    checked={this.checkCheck(tag_name)}
                    onChange={() => this.updateCheck(tag_name)}
                    />
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={this.props.text}>
                    { tag_name }
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

NOTE: I removed the `defaultChecked` and `value` properties in favor of `checked`.

See [example from React here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

And here is [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-grass-39f743?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: checked doesn't allow me to uncheck it

Comment: @SantoshLinkha Indeed. I've updated the code above. It was because the `updateCheck` was checking for the input value. So I changed it to receive a `tag_name` instead of the event.

Comment: Thank you for the update, +1 for your effort but it is still not working. I'll paste the full code above.

Comment: This works if you add the event `onClick = { (e) => e.target.checked = e.target.checked?false: true}`

Comment: How does that update your `updateCheck`?

Comment: I've updated the code, I guess your `updateCheck` is just expecting a boolean return value.